# how to decide rotation of a marker or pointer on a 3d .obj Object so that marker will look like it is pointing to some area of 3D object

Tags: reactjs, three.js, rotation, marker, raycasting

I am looking something like this ( https://jsfiddle.net/xg1o4ekr/378/ ) instead of globe imagine various other shapes of 3D object and marker coming outwards. Since my 3d object is not circle i cannot use the given  above code 
On clicking a loaded .obj 3D model, there will a pointer rendered on a clicked position(raycaster is used). using three js geometry shapes i have created a pointer. that pointer will render on a clicked position. how to determine pointer’s rotation. (it should dynamically decide the rotation of the pointer)

```
onMouseClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // calculate objects intersecting the picking ray
    var intersects = this.getIntersects(event.layerX, event.layerY);
    if (intersects.length > 0) {
        var res = intersects.filter(function (res) {
            return res && res.object;
        })[0];
        if (res && res.object) {
            this.selectedObject = res.object;
            console.log(res);
            const Pointer = this.createPointer();
            var g2 = new THREE.Group();
            g2.add(Pointer.cone);
            g2.add(Pointer.sphere);
            g2.position.set(res.point.x, res.point.y, res.point.z);
            //g2.rotation.set(res.point.x, res.point.y, res.point.z); //not working fine

            g2.rotateX(0.7);
            g2.rotateZ(0.9);
            g2.rotateY(1);// not working fine
            this.scene.add(g2);
        }
    }
}

getIntersects = (x, y) => {
    x = (x / this.width) * 2 - 1;
    y = - (y / this.height) * 2 + 1;
    this.mouseVector.set(x, y);
    this.raycaster.setFromCamera(this.mouseVector, this.camera);
    return this.raycaster.intersectObject(this.group, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. It's late here so i wont be able to try code, but maybe this helps?

Does the object you are clicking on have normals? 
You can find it in intersets[0].face.normal (or .vertexNormals).
You can align the pointer with that..

```
var normal = intersects[0].face.normal:
var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0); //(or maybe -1? i'm not sure, play around)
g2.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(axis, normal);
```

and if you want to set the pointer at a distance from the surface;

```
var distance = 4;
g2.position.add( normal.multiplyScalar(distance) );
```

Also, instead of creating a pointer everytime, why not creating it once and do pointer.clone()?

Comment: above code is working thanks :) i have one doubt suppose i have .obj format of a single piece of cloth. its front and backside shares same coordinates. how to determine its front or back side? if i am gonna save the coordinates details in database and through that coordinates i want to render pointers/markers again.

Comment: Great! Yay I helped.I understand your question I tried it out and there's no way to detemine on which side of the material you are raycasting.. 
That's a tricky one and a whole new question by itself I think. The only workaround I can think of is to use the position/direction vector of the camera to figure out on what side of the cloth you are (in respect to the normal direction).

Comment: hi i tried   var normal = intersects[0].face.normal;
                var axis = new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0);  
          pointer.position.set(res.point.x.toFixed(4), res.point.y.toFixed(4),res.point.z.toFixed(4));
                pointer.quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(axis, normal);

Comment: above code is working fine for obj format model but not for GLTF and FBX format. what to do?

Comment: I'm not sure. Does it give an error in the console? Could it be that there are no normals on the gltf/fbx models?

Comment: No console error! Pin is not adjusting properly after clicking on 3D model!  Half pin is going inside the 3D model and half outside with weird rotation.

Comment: huh that is super weird.. maybe re-generating the normals helps? on the model do `model.geometry.computeVertexNormals()` If that doesn't help i wouldn't know. Then maybe put in in a codepen example and re-post the question.

Comment: i tried computevertexnormals. in few 3d models it is working fine in few it is not. ok thanks